# How to get all  elements that are highlighted

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get all of the elements in a user highlighted area.  The problem is that I don't know how to traverse to different parts of the DOM, when the elements are on a different part of the tree.  My code so far can only get the elements off the startContainer of the selection range.  Do I need some sort of recursion?  Here is my code:

```
    getSelectedElementTags:function() 
{
    var range, sel, container;
    sel = content.window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt) 
    {
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) 
        {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);              
        }
    } 
    else 
    {       
        range = content.window.createRange();
        range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
        range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
        alert("range created");
    }


    if (range)
    {
        container = range["startContainer"];
        var elms = container.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("*");          
        elmlist = "parent: "+container.parentNode.tagName + " (" + elms.length + ")\n";
        for (i in elms)
        {
            if (elms[i].tagName != null)
            {
                elmlist += elms[i].tagName+"\n";
            }
        }

        alert(elmlist);
    }
},
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Which browsers must this work for (please don't state all, as I doubt Netscape 4 will be supported).

Comment: Just Firefox, since this is for an extension.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/TreeWalker) using [`document.createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTreeWalker). An example is below. It lists all elements that are partially or fully selected. You can easily change the behaviour by modifying the parameters passed to `document.createTreeWalker`.

Note that in Firefox you don't need to check for the existence of the `getRangeAt` method of a selection. This check is only required for older versions of WebKit. Also, IE < 9 does not support TreeWalker or Range, so the following won't work in those browsers.

**Edit** Fixed as per comments below.

```
function rangeIntersectsNode(range, node) {
    var nodeRange;
    if (range.intersectsNode) {
        return range.intersectsNode(node);
    } else {
        nodeRange = node.ownerDocument.createRange();
        try {
            nodeRange.selectNode(node);
        } catch (e) {
            nodeRange.selectNodeContents(node);
        }

        return range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_START, nodeRange) == -1 &&
            range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_END, nodeRange) == 1;
    }
}

function getSelectedElementTags(win) {
    var range, sel, elmlist, treeWalker, containerElement;
    sel = win.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }

    if (range) {
        containerElement = range.commonAncestorContainer;
        if (containerElement.nodeType != 1) {
            containerElement = containerElement.parentNode;
        }

        treeWalker = win.document.createTreeWalker(
            containerElement,
            NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
            function(node) { return rangeIntersectsNode(range, node) ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT; },
            false
        );

        elmlist = [treeWalker.currentNode];
        while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
            elmlist.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
        }

        console.log(elmlist);
    }
}

<input type="button" onclick="getSelectedElementTags(window)" value="Get selected elements">
```

Comment: Thanks alot Tim and it works great. Just one small problem... when one element is selected, the list is empty.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way, but I solved it by testing if the startContainer and endContainer of the range were the same.  If they were the same,  I would skip doing the treewalker and just get the parentNode of the startContainer.

Comment: You're right. There were two problems: first, I'd forgotten to include the first node in the TreeWalker in the list, and second that if the whole selection was contained within a single text node, no elements would be returned. Both now fixed in the answer.

Comment: will this work in IE too? i see a possible problem with the range object

Comment: @Thariama: No, this won't work for IE < 9, but there's a comment under the question saying that the OP only cares about Firefox. I'll put a note on the answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks alot Tim. it works great and solved my problem.