# How do I get the visible text of a range? (createRange)

Tags: javascript, dom, range

The string returned by .toString() on a range created by document.createRange(...) will contain things like the inner part of script and style tags. (At least using current version of Chrome.)

Is there a way to get just the visible text?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that seems reasonable and at least tentative standard compliant. (My guess, without checking, is that the standards perhaps does not handle all details in a case like this yet, but that the current implementation in Chrome seems useful and might become standard.)

The solution is simply to first create a document fragment from the range:

```
    var fragment = r.cloneContents();
```

Then just walk the fragment the way you would walk a sub tree in the DOM. Do not enter nodes like "SCRIPT" and "STYLE". Collect the "#text" nodes.

Comment: Yes, this will work and I'd say is the easiest way. You can also walk the nodes in the range without the cost of creating a clone of its contents. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7784176/96100

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will keep it in mind. (Don't you have to do the adjustment for partial selected nodes at the end too?)

Comment: Yes, but that's not too hard. If `startContainer` is a text node, for example, you just need `range.startContainer.data.slice(range.startOffset)` for the contribution from the partially selected node at the start. Unless the range `endContainer` is the same node, of course. `cloneContents()` is definitely easier.