# contenteditable what chlidren are selected in text range?

Tags: javascript, selection, wysiwyg, contenteditable

So I have a contenteditable div with multiple child paragraphs:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
    <p>Paragraph3</p>
    <p>Paragraph4</p>
</div>
```

So with `window.getSelection()` I get what text is selected, I know that if it `startContainer, startOffset` I can get where the range begins, and `endContainer, endOffset` where it ends.
But if my selection streches across multiple children paragraphs, how can I tell which children are selected?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like the one in the following answer and filter the array of nodes to only include `<p>` elements:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784176/96100