# Get all nodes in selected range?

Tags: javascript, selection

I'm using a `contenteditable` div to edit html content, and for some purpose, I need to get all nodes in selected range (`window.getSelection()`). I don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

I just find the solution.

[JS: Get array of all selected nodes in contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784176/6279975)

Comment: All nodes inside the `div` or all in the current document?

Comment: In the selected range.

Comment: Either mark this as a duplicate or delete the question.