# put span on selected text

Tags: javascript, dom, selection, textrange

how to make selected text stay surrounded by a span without breaking any Tag-element (javascript)

one exaple:

original text:

```
<p> a foo </p>
<p> another bar </p>
```

selected:

a fo`o

anoth`er bar

I do not want break the html nesting structure:

```
 <p> a fo<span>o </p>
<p> anoth</span>er bar </p>
```

I need something like this:

```
 <p> a fo<span>o </span></p>
 <p> <span>anoth</span>er bar </p>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why <b>hello <span>how are you</span>?</b> can't be used? It's valid HTML.

Comment: yes it is valid html,what I do not want to is it: <b> hello <span>   how are yo </b> </span> , for example

Comment: Take a look at [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/), it uses a combination of wrapper elements and classes to achieve something similar ([example](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html))

Comment: yes, if I've seen rangy, but I will not use it because it dont do that i need , I need save this html in a server for seen later .

Comment: Grabbing the HTML is just a matter of getting the `innerHTML` of the container element, I still believe rangy would save you some time...

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Imagine this:

```
<p> a foo </p>
<p> another bar </p>
```

resulting in:

a foo
another bar

Now if a user selects only a portion, lets say:

a fo`o

anoth`er bar

you break the html nesting structure:

```
 <p> a fo<span>o </p>
<p> anoth</span>er bar </p>
```

This is impossible to achieve with only one tag.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to iterate through each character in the selected text, grouping the characters by the DOM node in which they reside.  After you've created the groups, you'll want to wrap each group within the `<span>` tags.

You could do this by looking at the `anchorNode` and `focusNode` properties of the selection object, as well as testing other plausable nodes (ie. all children of the common parent/ancestor of the anchor and focus nodes) with the `containsNode()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482832/how-to-get-all-elements-that-are-highlighted) excellent treeWalker implementation, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A46UL/11/).
Please let me know if this works for you. Side note, use rangy it is awesome.

EDIT: Nope, wait, fixed.

Comment: its  good!!but not works very good if you select "er" in "another bar"

Comment: What problems are you having? Note: this was made only with firefox in mind, I don't know how well it will work in other browsers.

Comment: Correct, i need to add a condition for single element. I'll modify and get back to you in a sec.

Comment: if you modify it can you make for modify inner spans in the selection

Comment: case underscores and old selected text change attributes of element with the new sapan I'd appreciate it,thanks!

Comment: i'm trying, but i'll probably have to get back to you tomorrow because it is very late where i am. if you need an immediate solution, try one of the above or rangy. don't worry, i will give it a shot.

Comment: dont worry :), i will see rangy

Comment: Well that is ultimately the best solution, but i just fixed the bug. I just saw your other requests. Perhaps open another question? I do not fully understand what you require there.