# How to remove highlighted multiple html contenteditable elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I highlight multiple HTML elements and remove them by pressing the `Backspace` key? WordPress block editor and [Editor.js](https://editorjs.io/) has this feature. Users can select/ Highlight multiple `block` and remove them by pressing the `Backspace` key.
From this code below, If I highlight by selecting(mouse) **not by clicking** the `.block-1, .block-2, .block-3` and press `Backspace` key then it should delete these elements.

**[NOTE]**

1. Every block should have contenteditable attribute.
2. Please, go to [Editor.js](https://editorjs.io/) first for demo what I exact want.

```html
<div class="block-1" contenteditable="true"> 1st Block </div>
<div class="block-2" contenteditable="true"> 2nd Block </div>
<div class="block-3" contenteditable="true"> 3rd Block </div>
<div class="block-4" contenteditable="true"> 4th Block </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything on your own to achieve this?

Comment: I don't have any idea. How can I select multiple content editable div and delete them on btn press

Comment: Somebody is on a downvote spree. But perhaps the question is just not clear.

Comment: @html_programmer Sorry for that, I don't know anything. But my question is now clear enough to get my answer. Please visit editor.js and then highlight some block by mouse and press backspace. It will delete these blocks. I need the same feature.

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can select and deselect  the `block`  by highlighting the text inside it

Comment: @Md.Tahazzot Can you check the answer, i updated it three times, now i think works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need 2 listeners:

- 1 - on mouseup, which catches selected text, and use [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to get all the highlighted elements and toggle `selected` class on `.block`s.
- 2 - on keyup, which will catch backspace

---

### Edit:

Used [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482832/how-to-get-all-elements-that-are-highlighted) and improved the answer .

```js
$(document).on({
  'keyup': function(e) {
    if (e.which == 8)
      $('div.block.selected').remove();
  },
  'mouseup': getSelectedElementTags
});


function rangeIntersectsNode(range, node) {
  var nodeRange;
  if (range.intersectsNode) {
    return range.intersectsNode(node);
  } else {
    nodeRange = node.ownerDocument.createRange();
    try {
      nodeRange.selectNode(node);
    } catch (e) {
      nodeRange.selectNodeContents(node);
    }

    return range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_START, nodeRange) == -1 &&
      range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_END, nodeRange) == 1;
  }
}

function getSelectedElementTags() {
  var win = window;
  var range, sel, elmlist, treeWalker, containerElement;
  sel = win.getSelection();
  if (sel.toString().length == 0) return
  if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  }

  if (range) {
    containerElement = range.commonAncestorContainer;
    if (containerElement.nodeType != 1) {
      containerElement = containerElement.parentNode;
    }

    treeWalker = win.document.createTreeWalker(
      containerElement,
      NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
      function(node) {
        return rangeIntersectsNode(range, node) ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
      },
      false
    );

    elmlist = [treeWalker.currentNode];
    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
      elmlist.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
    }
    elmlist.forEach(function(e) {
      if ($(e).hasClass('block')) {
        $(e).toggleClass('selected');
      }
    });
    sel.empty()
  }
}
```

```css
div.block.selected {
  background-color: #ddf;
}

div.block {
  margin: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="block block-1" contenteditable="true"> 1st Block</div>
  <div class="block block-2" contenteditable="true"> 2nd Block </div>
  <div class="block block-3" contenteditable="true"> 3rd Block</div>
  <div class="block block-4"> 4th Block </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need all the block elements with contenteditable attr. Same as Editor.js/ WP block editor. (You get the idea)

Answer (score -1):

The CSS and the contenteditable attribute are not necessary. Here is the code

```js
var targeted;

document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target); // You can see here the targeted element
    if(event.target.id !== 'container') {
        targeted = event.target;
    } else {
        targeted = undefined;
    };
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 8 && targeted) {
        targeted.parentNode.removeChild(targeted);
    };
});
```

```css
#container {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}
#container div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div contenteditable="true">1</div>
    <div contenteditable="true">2</div>
    <div contenteditable="true">3</div>
    <div contenteditable="true">4</div>
    <div contenteditable="true">5</div>
</div>
```