# Selecting multiple content-editable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of content-editable `div`s on a page. I was unable to select the content of all the `div`s.

As every `div` is a separately editable one, as an alternative, on select and drag I want to highlight the `div`s. Like the one below:

[image]

```css
.editable {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Block 1</div>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Block 2</div>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Block 3</div>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

Please let me know how to achieve it using jquery or javascript.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: Ive answered a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685167/how-to-remove-highlighted-multiple-html-contenteditable-elements/63685415#63685415) check if it does answer your's.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to make the parent div `contenteditable` too:

```css
.editable {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Block 1</div>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Block 2</div>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Block 3</div>
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from my Angular application, maybe it will help a little:

```
    this.containerElement.nativeElement.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      document.getSelection()?.empty();
      this.containerElement.nativeElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    });

    this.containerElement.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      const selection = saveSelection(this.containerElement.nativeElement);

      this.containerElement.nativeElement.setAttribute(
        'contenteditable',
        false,
      );

      restoreSelection(this.containerElement.nativeElement, selection);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

selcting multiple div with same class name, can use jquery each function then you will get all div class name with indexes.

```
$('.editable').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).text()
});
```